# client to server communication in VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I made some code in vb.net which checks if a certain process is running, and returns a 1 if it is, or a 0 if it isn't. Now I want it to send a packet to my server or something which would log the IP of the client, or something similar.

What would be the easiest way to approach this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of different solutions to this task.  First, which comes to my mind is [WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663324) - maybe the easiest one as you do not think about opening ports, establishing the connections, parsing the input socket string and so on.

Here is on more link:

[Introducing Windows Communication Foundation in .NET Framework 4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ee958158.aspx)